# Find an element that has two CSS classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following DIV:

```
<div class="gallery home"></div>
```

And I have the Query:

```
  if ($('.gallery.home')) {
    console.log('home');
  }

  if ($('.gallery.showcase')) {
    console.log('showcase');
  }
```

The problem is that both `if` return true. Shouldn't only the first one return true?

I then tried using only Javascript the same happens:

```
  if (document.getElementsByClassName('.gallery.home')) {
    console.log('home');
  }

  if (document.getElementsByClassName('.gallery.showcase')) {
    console.log('showcase');
  }
```

How to match an element that has 2 classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('.gallery.showcase')` returns a jQuery wrapped list of objects which is true-ish even if no elements matched.

`$('.gallery.showcase').length > 0` would be what you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('gallery showcase');
```

It's space-delimited and without the dot!

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation it says;

> You may also call getElementsByClassName() on any element; it will
>   return only elements which are descendants of the specified root
>   element with the given class **names**.

Also, you can see in the examples:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

If you want to select a specific element you can use `querySelector`

```
if (document.querySelectorAll('.gallery.home')) {
  console.log('home');
}

if (document.querySelectorAll('.gallery.showcase')) {
  console.log('showcase');
}
```

For the jquery part `$('')` will always return an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare it with a single or separate condition.

> **Single Condition Like**

```
if($('.gallery.home').length > 0)
if($('.gallery.showcase').length > 0)
```

> **Separate Condition Like**

```
if($('.gallery').length > 0 && $('.home').length > 0)

if($('.gallery').length > 0 && $('.showcase').length > 0)
```

```js
console.log($('.gallery').length > 0 && $('.home').length > 0)

console.log($('.gallery').length > 0 && $('.showcase').length > 0)

console.log($('.gallery.home').length > 0)

console.log($('.gallery.showcase').length > 0)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery home"></div>
```